Why is $\lim_\limits{t\to1^-}\sum_\limits{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^t} = \text{undefined}$?
Why is $\lim_\limits{t\to1^-}\sum_\limits{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^t} = \text{undefined}$?
I tried this on W|A and got $\lim_\limits{t\to1^+}\sum_\limits{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^t} = \infty$ as expected, but it also says $\lim_\limits{t\to1^-}\sum_\limits{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^t} = \text{undefined}$, that's very weird and seems wrong, specially since when you do the limit "manually" (e.g. $\sum_\limits{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^{0.9999}}$) you get the expected answer of $\infty$, is W|A right here? If so, why?

That sum does not converge for any $t<1$, so you cannot approach $1$ from below.

@Gary well the series is identically $\infty$ for all $t\in (-\infty,1]$, so because we are in a situation where we’re discussing infinite limits, we should say the limit is $\infty$. Wolfram Alpha probably just can’t handle it.

The internal series diverges to infinity when $t<1$. So what is $\lim\infty$? That is not defined.

@peek-a-boo $t\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^t}$ is not defined on any interval of the form $(x_0,1)$ with $x_0<1$ as a real valued function, therefore taking the limit does not make sense. The accumulation point should be approached within the domain of the function.

@Gary sure, it’s not a real-valued function, and I never claimed it was. Here we are clearly dealing with infinities, so it is very much reasonable to consider functions taking values in the extended reals, there is the “standard” topology. And there obviously the limit is $\infty$ since the function is identically $\infty$ on $(-\infty,1]$. But ok, if you only want to consider it as a real-valued function, then of course the limit doesn’t exist. So, I guess we should emphasize to OP that the precise choice of domain and target space (which are part of the definition of a function) matters.
